# Верстка и позиционирование div-блоков

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Добрый день подскажите пожалуйста как сверстать div'ы таким образом: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

чтоб не нужно было каждый див отдельно позиционировать?

Answer (score 3):

а все вроде нашел вариант на grid, вот может кому-то поможет:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.item8 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>  
  <div class="item9">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделано на **flex**:

```css
div.container{
  width:120px;
  height:30px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:start;
}
div.item{
  width:30px;
  height:15px;
  font-size:0;
  border:2px solid #000;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div.item:nth-child(3){
  height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

С масштабом разберетесь сами надеюсь))

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
  width: 440px;
  height: 210px;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
  
    .block div {
      border: 1px solid #000;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 1px;
}
      
      .block div:nth-child(2) {
        height: 200px;
      }
      .block div:nth-child(5) {
        margin-top: -100px;
      }
      .block div:nth-child(6) {
         margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: 106px;
      }
      .block div:nth-child(7) {
        margin-top: -102px;
        margin-left: 314px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
</div>
```